# {Arnold Dynamical System I, 1992} f diffeomorphism => derivative of f isomorphism

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, proof-verification, differential-geometry, vector-spaces

Let $f$ be a diffeomorphism of $M$ onto $N$ (both $M$,$N$ are smooth manifold). Prove that the mapping $f_{*x}$ is a vector-space isomorphism
between $T_xM$ and $T_xN$.

---

Here is a proof:

Let $x=f^{-1}(y) \in M,\, y\in N$ and $h\in M, k\in N$ and I denote $U=f_{*x}$ and $V=f^{-1}_{x*}$. We know that $U,V$ are linear maps.

We have:
$$
f(x+h)=f(x)+Uh+o(|h|)
$$
$$
f^{-1}(y+k)=f^{-1}(y)+Vk+o(|k|)
$$

Then
$$
y+k = f(f^{-1}(y)+Vk+o(|k|))=y+U(Vk+o(|k|)) +o(|Vk+o(|k|)|)
$$
which yields
$$
k=UVk
$$
for every $k$ so $U$ is invertible and $U^{-1}=V$.

Comment: You could use the chain rule and prove the theorem in one line.

Comment: Oh yeah indeed !

Comment: Your operations only make sense if the manifolds are affine spaces. That could be accomplished locally by considering charts of the manifolds. On curved space in general you can not simply add a tangent vector to a point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Denote by $g=f^{-1}$ we have using the chain rule,

$$
d(g\circ f)[x](h) = dg[f(x)](df[x](h))
$$
which gives
$$
h = V(Uh)
$$
hence $U^{-1}=V$.